# Mostrar conjunto de dados com SELECT

Tags: sql, mysql

Opa, então, estou com um problema para achar (mostrar) alguns dados que está sendo pedido, preciso que mostre os seguintes dados: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ypczD.png

e sempre aparece o erro que é uma lista ambígua (Não sei se está correto mas é o erro 1052)

Segue programação completa:

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS `desi_loja`;
CREATE DATABASE `desi_loja`;
USE `desi_loja`;

CREATE TABLE `produtos` (
  `produto_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nome` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `quantidade_estoque` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `preco_unitario` decimal(4,2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`produto_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
INSERT INTO `produtos` VALUES (1,'Prato Plástico Refeição',70,1.21);
INSERT INTO `produtos` VALUES (2,'Pernil Suíno',49,4.65);
INSERT INTO `produtos` VALUES (3,'Alface Romana',38,3.35);
INSERT INTO `produtos` VALUES (4,'Brócolis Chinês',90,4.53);
INSERT INTO `produtos` VALUES (5,'Molho Ranch',94,1.63);
INSERT INTO `produtos` VALUES (6,'Baguete Pequeno',14,2.39);
INSERT INTO `produtos` VALUES (7,'Broto de ervilha',98,3.29);
INSERT INTO `produtos` VALUES (8,'Suco de Framboesa',26,0.74);
INSERT INTO `produtos` VALUES (9,'Fruta Olho do Dragão - Longan',67,2.26);
INSERT INTO `produtos` VALUES (10,'Vassoura Multiuso',6,1.09);


CREATE TABLE `transportadoras` (
  `transportadora_id` smallint(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nome` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`transportadora_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
INSERT INTO `transportadoras` VALUES (1,'Acme LLC');
INSERT INTO `transportadoras` VALUES (2,'Fastco');
INSERT INTO `transportadoras` VALUES (3,'Satturn LLC');
INSERT INTO `transportadoras` VALUES (4,'Bombom S/A');
INSERT INTO `transportadoras` VALUES (5,'WMP Ltda.');


CREATE TABLE `clientes` (
  `cliente_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `primeiro_nome` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `sobrenome` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `data_aniversario` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `telefone` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `endereco` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `cidade` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `estado` char(2) NOT NULL,
  `pontos` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`cliente_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
INSERT INTO `clientes` VALUES (1,'Barbara','Caffrey','1986-03-28','4781932-9754','Avenida Osvaldo Veiga','Blumenau','SC',2273);
INSERT INTO `clientes` VALUES (2,'Ines','Ushfield','1986-04-13','4804427-9456','Rua Rui Barbosa','Capivari de Baixo','SC',947);
INSERT INTO `clientes` VALUES (3,'Fred','Borges','1985-02-07','4719724-7869','Avenida Primavera, 251 ','Criciuma','SC',2967);
INSERT INTO `clientes` VALUES (4,'Antonio','Rosa','1974-04-14','4407231-8017','Rua Arapongas, 5982','Ponta Grossa','PR',457);
INSERT INTO `clientes` VALUES (5,'Clemente','Bento','1973-11-07',NULL,'Travessa Bom Jesus, 15','Manaus','AM',3675);
INSERT INTO `clientes` VALUES (6,'Elke','Tancredo','1991-09-04','5312480-8498','Avenida Macau, 4219','Canoas','RS',3073);
INSERT INTO `clientes` VALUES (7,'Irene','Dias','1964-08-30','8615641-4759','Rua Tiradentes, 50','Natal','RN',1672);
INSERT INTO `clientes` VALUES (8,'Thalita','Nandi','1993-07-17','1941527-3977','Avenida Paulista, 538','São Paulo','SP',205);
INSERT INTO `clientes` VALUES (9,'Romulo','Rios','1992-05-23','1559181-3744','Rua Chico Mendes, 4568','Bom Sucesso','RJ',1486);
INSERT INTO `clientes` VALUES (10,'Levy','Mendes','1969-10-13','1404246-3370','Avenida Atlanta, 10','Maceio','AL',796);


CREATE TABLE `pedido_situacoes` (
  `pedido_situacao_id` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `nome` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`pedido_situacao_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
INSERT INTO `pedido_situacoes` VALUES (1,'Processado');
INSERT INTO `pedido_situacoes` VALUES (2,'Transportado');
INSERT INTO `pedido_situacoes` VALUES (3,'Entregue');


CREATE TABLE `pedidos` (
  `pedido_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cliente_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `pedido_data` date NOT NULL,
  `situacao` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `comentarios` varchar(2000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `data_transporte` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `transportadora_id` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`pedido_id`),
  KEY `fk_pedidos_clientes_idx` (`cliente_id`),
  KEY `fk_pedidos_transportadoras_idx` (`transportadora_id`),
  KEY `fk_pedidos_pedido_situacoes_idx` (`situacao`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_pedidos_clientes` FOREIGN KEY (`cliente_id`) REFERENCES `clientes` (`cliente_id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_pedidos_pedido_situacoes` FOREIGN KEY (`situacao`) REFERENCES `pedido_situacoes` (`pedido_situacao_id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_pedidos_transportadoras` FOREIGN KEY (`transportadora_id`) REFERENCES `transportadoras` (`transportadora_id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
INSERT INTO `pedidos` VALUES (1,6,'2019-01-30',1,NULL,NULL,NULL);
INSERT INTO `pedidos` VALUES (2,7,'2018-08-02',2,NULL,'2018-08-03',4);
INSERT INTO `pedidos` VALUES (3,8,'2017-12-01',1,NULL,NULL,NULL);
INSERT INTO `pedidos` VALUES (4,2,'2017-01-22',1,NULL,NULL,NULL);
INSERT INTO `pedidos` VALUES (5,5,'2017-08-25',2,'','2017-08-26',3);
INSERT INTO `pedidos` VALUES (6,10,'2018-11-18',1,'Aliquam erat volutpat. In congue.',NULL,NULL);
INSERT INTO `pedidos` VALUES (7,2,'2018-09-22',2,NULL,'2018-09-23',4);
INSERT INTO `pedidos` VALUES (8,5,'2018-06-08',1,'Mauris enim leo, rhoncus sed, vestibulum sit amet, cursus id, turpis.',NULL,NULL);
INSERT INTO `pedidos` VALUES (9,10,'2017-07-05',2,'Nulla mollis molestie lorem. Quisque ut erat.','2017-07-06',1);
INSERT INTO `pedidos` VALUES (10,6,'2018-04-22',2,NULL,'2018-04-23',2);


CREATE TABLE `pedido_itens` (
  `pedido_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `produto_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `quantidade` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `preco_unitario` decimal(4,2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`pedido_id`,`produto_id`),
  KEY `fk_pedido_itens_produtos_idx` (`produto_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_pedido_itens_pedidos` FOREIGN KEY (`pedido_id`) REFERENCES `pedidos` (`pedido_id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_pedido_itens_produtos` FOREIGN KEY (`produto_id`) REFERENCES `produtos` (`produto_id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
INSERT INTO `pedido_itens` VALUES (1,4,4,3.74);
INSERT INTO `pedido_itens` VALUES (2,1,2,9.10);
INSERT INTO `pedido_itens` VALUES (2,4,4,1.66);
INSERT INTO `pedido_itens` VALUES (2,6,2,2.94);
INSERT INTO `pedido_itens` VALUES (3,3,10,9.12);
INSERT INTO `pedido_itens` VALUES (4,3,7,6.99);
INSERT INTO `pedido_itens` VALUES (4,10,7,6.40);
INSERT INTO `pedido_itens` VALUES (5,2,3,9.89);
INSERT INTO `pedido_itens` VALUES (6,1,4,8.65);
INSERT INTO `pedido_itens` VALUES (6,2,4,3.28);
INSERT INTO `pedido_itens` VALUES (6,3,4,7.46);
INSERT INTO `pedido_itens` VALUES (6,5,1,3.45);
INSERT INTO `pedido_itens` VALUES (7,3,7,9.17);
INSERT INTO `pedido_itens` VALUES (8,5,2,6.94);
INSERT INTO `pedido_itens` VALUES (8,8,2,8.59);
INSERT INTO `pedido_itens` VALUES (9,6,5,7.28);
INSERT INTO `pedido_itens` VALUES (10,1,10,6.01);
INSERT INTO `pedido_itens` VALUES (10,9,9,4.28);

CREATE TABLE `desi_loja`.`pedido_item_observacoes` (
  `observacao_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `pedido_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `produto_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `observacao` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`observacao_id`));

INSERT INTO `pedido_item_observacoes` (`observacao_id`, `pedido_id`, `produto_id`, `observacao`) VALUES ('1', '2', '1', 'Primeira observação');
INSERT INTO `pedido_item_observacoes` (`observacao_id`, `pedido_id`, `produto_id`, `observacao`) VALUES ('2', '2', '1', 'Segunda observação');

SELECT pedido_data AS "data do pedido", pedido_id AS "Nº do pedido", preco_unitario * quantidade AS "Valor Pedido", primeiro_nome + sobrenome AS "Nome do Cliente", situacao AS "Situação do pedido"
FROM pedidos,pedido_itens,clientes,pedido_situacoes
GROUP BY pedido_id
ORDER BY pedido_id
```

Segue a programação somente da parte de pesquisa:

```
SELECT pedido_data AS "data do pedido", pedido_id AS "Nº do pedido", preco_unitario * quantidade AS "Valor Pedido", primeiro_nome + sobrenome AS "Nome do Cliente", situacao AS "Situação do pedido"
FROM pedidos,pedido_itens,clientes,pedido_situacoes
GROUP BY pedido_id
ORDER BY pedido_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"o erro que é uma lista ambígua"* isso significa que, algum campo que tem no comando, seja no `SELECT`, `WHERE`, `ORDER BY` ou `GROUP BY` existe em mais de uma tabela com o mesmo nome. Nesse caso é preciso dizer "de qual tabela" é o campo que quer usar.

Por exemplo "pedido_id" existe nas tabelas "pedidos" e "pedido_itens", então se quer usar o valor da tabela "pedidos", deve usar "pedidos.pedido_id".

Além disso, adicionou várias tabelas no `FROM` e não disse como elas estão ligadas, precisa fazer isso usando `JOIN`. O fato de haver ou não uma chave estrangeira não diz ao para "automaticamente" usar o campo, é preciso dizer explicitamente.

Veja esse exemplo abaixo:

```
SELECT pedido_data AS "data do pedido", 
       pedidos.pedido_id AS "Nº do pedido", 
       preco_unitario * quantidade AS "Valor Pedido", 
       primeiro_nome + sobrenome AS "Nome do Cliente", situacao AS "Situação do pedido"
 FROM pedidos
INNER JOIN pedido_itens ON pedidos.pedido_id = pedido_itens.pedido_id
INNER JOIN clientes ON pedidos.cliente_id = clientes.cliente_id
INNER JOIN pedido_situacoes ON pedidos.situacao  = pedido_situacoes.pedido_situacao_id
ORDER BY pedidos.pedido_id
```

Veja que todos os campos que são "ambíguos" foram prefixados com o nome da tabela (poderia usar um *alias* para simplificar o nome também).

Para além disso, fiz o join (user o `INNER JOIN` nesse caso) entre todas as tabelas, ou ia trazer muitos resultados duplicados.

Por fim, removi o `GROUP BY`, porque não adianta agrupar só por pedido_id, e os outros campos no `SELECT` não serem agrupados.

Pode ver funcionando aqui: [https://www.db-fiddle.com/](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/faHS5XCcFxo8K7yZBbaVFZ/0)

Answer (score -1):

Você esqueceu de usar INNER JOIN e a sua sintaxe em algumas partes estava errada. Consegui ter o seguinte retorno (Que eu acredito ser da forma que você quer):
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Usando a seguinte query:

```
 SELECT pedidos.pedido_data AS "Data do Pedido", pedidos.pedido_id AS "N° do Pedido", produtos.preco_unitario * pedido_itens.quantidade as "Valor Pedido", CONCAT(clientes.primeiro_nome, clientes.sobrenome) as "Nome do Cliente", pedidos.situacao AS "Situação do Pedido" FROM Pedidos INNER JOIN pedido_itens ON pedidos.pedido_id = pedido_itens.pedido_id INNER JOIN clientes ON pedidos.cliente_id = clientes.cliente_id INNER JOIN produtos ON pedido_itens.produto_id = produtos.produto_id ORDER BY pedidos.pedido_id;
```